# Allowing users to organize folders and files on a Linux based cloud server

Tags: linux, open-source, file-management

We are looking for a solution, preferably open source, that has an API that we could invoke to allow our end users to create folders and files on our Linux based cloud server, and organize them as per their preference (e.g. moving notes across folders, creating sub-solders etc.).  The idea is to provide the end users a local filesystem type abstraction for their cloud space, with each directory and file also being addressable by its own URL (like what Dropbox already does).  Specifically the operations that we are looking for include:

- Creating a folder
- Saving a note to a folder
- Moving a note to a different folder
- Moving a folder under a different folder
- Deleting a note
- Deleting a folder
- Navigating to a particular note

We don’t want to be constrained to physically organize the notes and directories in the same layout as what the user visualizes.